# Multiple Contact-form PHP inside modal is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use multiple contact forms in modal windows. I am using Bootstrap, PHP and some JS. I cant find out why it`s not working. Please help.

My html for ONE form (I have 15 same forms):

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal" id="modal-24">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h2 class="text-center">LEDENICA<sup>TM</sup><br>ШАМПИНЬОНЫ</h2>
          <img src="images/line.png" alt="line" class="img-responsive heading-line">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-23" data-dismiss="modal"><img alt="left" class="left-modal-control" src="images/chevron-left.png"></a>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-25" data-dismiss="modal"><img alt="right" class="right-modal-control" src="images/chevron-right.png"></a>
          <div class="row modal-row">
            <div class="image-col col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" alt="product" src="images/tm-4.png">
            </div>
            <div class="info-col col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hr-bottom">
                <p>Наши грибы собираются на пике созревания и моментально замораживаются, сохраняя истинный вкус, задуманный природой. Таким образом, Вы можете круглый год наслаждаться вкусными и полезными грибами Ledenica™.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <p class="red">Вес продукта:</p>
                <p class="desc">0,400 кг</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <p class="red">Срок годности:</p>
                <p class="desc">24 мес</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <p class="red">Условия хранения:</p>
                <p class="desc">До -18<sup>o</sup> С</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  hr-top">
                <p class="red">Пищевая ценность в 100г</p>
              </div>
              <div class="info-table">
                <div class="table-content-1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>Энергетическая ценность</p>
                </div>
                <div class="table-content-2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>113 кДж/27 ккал</p>
                </div>
                <div class="table-content-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>Белки</p>
                </div>
                <div class="table-content-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>4,5г</p>
                </div>
                <div class="table-content-5 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>Углеводы</p>
                </div>
                <div class="table-content-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <p>0,1г</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p><span class="red">Состав:</span> шампиньоны</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  hr-top">
                <p>Запросить прайс-лист</p>
              </div>
              <form id="contact-form-modal" method="post" action="contact-modal.php" role="form">
                <div class="messages"></div>
                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="modal-col-first col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-modal">
                      <input id="form_email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-modal" required="required" data-error="Пожалуйста, введите email." placeholder="Email">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-send" value="ПОЛУЧИТЬ ПРАЙС">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>**
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/contact-modal.js"></script>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

// configure
$from         = 'myemail@gmail.com>'; 
$sendTo       = '<myemail@gmail.com>';
$subject      = 'New message from online form';
$fields       = array('email' => 'email'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage    = 'Спасибо.';
$errorMessage = 'Извините, ошибка.';

// let's do the sending
try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from online form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

My JS:

```
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form-modal').validator();

    $('#contact-form-modal').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact-modal.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form-modal').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form-modal')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

After form submit the 1 Form everything work correct. But if I submit other forms it reloads the window with result "Thank you". So, I can see only "thank you" on white. But I know that my result message must appear without reloading. How can I overwrite the JS to make all my forms correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your Email is empty because your post data has email with a small "e" and in your php you search for Email with an Uppercase "E".

Second in your javascript you check in the "if", if default is prevented... but I don't get where you prevent the default. Change your javascript to

```
$('#contact-form-modal').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

and than leave out the if-statement.

Otherwise try to make some debug outputs on interessting spots in your code with var_dump in php or console.log in javascript to see what's going on in your code ;)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for reply. Yes, you are right about my mistake with small "e". But the main problem is still actual - Ajax is not working.

Comment: Hello, Andre. I find out one strange moment. I have 15 modal window on this website. The first one works correct via AJAX. All others open white window with "Thank you". All this modals and forms are same. Can you please suggest what the problem is?